# How to specify a struct with a multi-column unique index for Gorm?

Tags: go, go-gorm

How do I define my `struct`s to specify a multi-column unique index to Gorm in Go?

Such as:

```
type Something struct {
    gorm.Model
    First  string `sql:"unique_index:unique_index_with_second"`
    Second string `sql:"unique_index:unique_index_with_first"`
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

this is how you do it: You need to use the gorm struct tag and specify that the index is unique

```
type Something struct {
    gorm.Model
    First  string `gorm:"index:idx_name,unique"`
    Second string `gorm:"index:idx_name,unique"`
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can define same unique index for each column.

```
type Something struct {
    gorm.Model
    First  string `sql:"unique_index:idx_first_second"`
    Second string `sql:"unique_index:idx_first_second"`
}
```

Answer (score 10):

for latest version of gorm (or for my case)
this works:

```golang
type Something struct {
    gorm.Model
    First  string `gorm:"uniqueIndex:idx_first_second"`
    Second string `gorm:"uniqueIndex:idx_first_second"`
}
```